# SharePoint 2010: How to extract personalized web part property for all users

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, personalization

### Background:

I have a built-in-house custom SharePoint 2010 web part, inheriting from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart`, which has a property defined like so:

```
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User)]
[WebBrowsable(true)]
[WebDisplayName("...")]
[WebDescription("...")]
[Category("...")]
public string CustomProp { get; set; }
```

The Powers-That-Be would like to know the value of the property for each of its 3,000 users. I'm already familiar with how to use the [SPLimitedWebPartManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.splimitedwebpartmanager.aspx) to extract the property in either ***shared view*** or ***my own personal view***, using code similar to:

```
var pageUrl = "/Pages/SomePage.aspx";
var limitedManager = SPContext.Current.Web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(
    pageUrl,
    PersonalizationScope.User); // or .Shared, if loading the shared value
var webPart = limitedManager.WebParts.OfType<MyWebPart>().FirstOrDefault();
var prop = webPart.CustomProp;
```

### So, the question:

I'm stuck on collecting this information for **all users**. Assuming I already have, or know how to retrieve, a list of login names or SPUser objects, how do I go about retrieving the web part property for all users? I can use suggestions in C#, VB.NET, or PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code - I haven't tested it but I think it should work.

```
const string absolutePageUrl = "http://spsite:5000/Pages/SomePage.aspx";

foreach (SPUser user in SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.AllUsers.Cast<SPUser>())
{
    if (!user.LoginName.StartsWith("DOMAIN NAME"))
        continue;

    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(absolutePageUrl, user.UserToken))
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        var mgr = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(absolutePageUrl, PersonalizationScope.User);
        var webPart = mgr.WebParts.OfType<MyWebPart>().FirstOrDefault();
        var prop = webPart.CustomProp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Nathan! This put me on the right track. I rolled a solution that involved direct SQL access, but this got me going using the supported API! A few things, and I'll upvote and mark as correct: swap `limitedManager` for `mgr`, and modify the `new SPSite()` call to use the site Guid (no constructor exists for `(string, usertoken)`). I'll post PowerShell adaptations of this code and of my direct-SQL approach, the the mark-as-answer is yours once the code syntax is corrected.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out - I've renamed limitedManager. That SPSite constructor does exist (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms469253.aspx) but it requires an absolute URL (so I've updated accordingly).